# Execute OSGI console commands programmatically

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, gogo-shell

Can someone please provide a working example on how to execute OSGI console commands programmatically?

I am loading OSGI through code and I want to execute OSGI console commands (I am receiving the commands through a different system). This is what I am doing as a simple test:

```
ServiceLoader<FrameworkFactory> frameworkFactoryService = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class);
FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = frameworkFactoryService.iterator().next();

Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String,String>();
config.put("org.osgi.framework.storage", "../workspace/.config");
config.put("org.osgi.framework.storage.clean", "onFirstInit");

framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);

framework.init();
framework.start();  

// install required bundles
String bundleLocation = "org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.8.0.20181108-1144.jar";
Bundle bundle = framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(bundleLocation);

bundleLocation = "org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.4.2.M20090103-1001-RCP20181108-1144.jar";
bundle = framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(bundleLocation);
bundle.start();

bundleLocation = "org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036.jar";
bundle = framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(bundleLocation);
bundle.start();

bundleLocation = "org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar";
bundle = framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(bundleLocation);
bundle.start();

bundleLocation = "org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605.jar";
bundle = framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(bundleLocation);
bundle.start();

bundleLocation = "org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.200.v20150929-1405.jar";
bundle = framework.getBundleContext().installBundle(bundleLocation);
bundle.start();

CommandProcessorImpl commandProcessor = new CommandProcessorImpl();
CommandSession commandSession = commandProcessor.createSession(System.in, System.out, System.err);

commandSession.execute("ss");
```

Everything loads correctly and if I loop through all bundles programmatically I can see everything is loaded and started. Unfortunately I am getting Exception "Command not found: ss" on the "execute" line. What am I doing wrong? Anyone with a simple working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting the `CommandProcessImpl` yourself. You should get the `CommandProcessor` service instead. The instance you created has no connection to the framework and can therefore not find any commands registered as services.

```
 BundleContext context = framework.getBundleContext();
 ServiceReference<CommandProcessor> cpr = 
     context.getServiceReference(CommandProcessor.class);
 CommandProcessor cp = context.getService(cpr);

 CommandSession session = cp.createSession(System.in, System.out, System.err);

 session.execute("lsb");
```

Clearly this code is not protected. Getting a service reference and then getting a service is really bad since services can come and go.

bnd has a remote agent (biz.aQute.bnd.remote) that you can easily call from an external process. It also has a bndremote program that you can run on any machine and then you can download the framework + bundles in that machine. This might be easier than building this yourself?

Comment: Thanks. This was a good guidance. I was missing the connection between the framework and the CommandProcessor as this post suggested. I also had to use Reflection as my code is running outside the OSGI environment and had to use classes from packages inside bundles during runtime. I will take a look at bnd as well.

Comment: If you want commands, register a service through the framework. It will be picked up. Much of what you want to do has been done a lot of times in many different settings. Unless this is a hobby project, get some help to not reinvent the wheel, and worse, make the many mistakes in this error prone field. Launchers are complicated!